# Getting AttributeError from child thread instead of normal exit

Tags: python, multithreading, debugging, attributeerror

I have multithreaded program that has a main thread that handles the calculator and client or server threads. For some reason when I try to start the client with invalid argument (-d 1, should be something like 2001:dead:30::5) instead of exiting and printing the help text it gives an attribute error from the calculator thread

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer

here is the error message

```
root@nyoa-VirtualBox:/home/nyoa# python trafgen6.py -c -d 1
Invalid address
closing client
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trafgen6.py", line 779, in <module>
    thread2.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 750, in start
    self.__started.wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 620, in wait
    self.__cond.wait(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 339, in wait
    waiter.acquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
Exception AttributeError: "'calculator' object has no attribute    'stoprequest'" in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7   /threading.pyc'> ignored
Unhandled exception in thread started by 
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

And here is my code responsible for this part

```
class Client(threading.Thread):

        threadLocal = threading.local()

        def __init__(self, host, port, rate, duration, parent = None):
          super(Client, self).__init__(parent)
          self.host = host
          self.port = port
          self.rate = rate
          self.duration = duration

        def run(self):
          self.stoprequest = threading.Event()
          self.threadLocal.sch = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
          self.threadLocal.next_time = time.time()
          self.threadLocal.sch.enterabs(self.threadLocal.next_time, 0, self.oneround, ())

          host = self.host
          port = self.port
          speed = self.rate
          duration = self.duration
          self.threadLocal.delay = 1.0 / (speed*128)
          n = bool(False)
          error = (False)
          openfile = open('1024')
          self.threadLocal.message = openfile.read()

          self.threadLocal.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
          self.threadLocal.s.setblocking(0)
          try:
                self.threadLocal.s.connect((host,port))
                self.threadLocal.s.send(self.threadLocal.message)
                time.sleep(0.1)
                if len(self.threadLocal.s.recvfrom(1500)) > 1:
                        n = (True)
          except IOError as (errno, strerror):
                if errno == -9:
                        print 'Invalid address'
                        error = (True)
                        os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
                if errno == 11:
                        print 'Connection failed'
                        error = (True)
                        os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
                if errno == -2:
                        print 'Name or service unknown'
                        error = (True)
                        os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)

          if n == True:
                self.timeout = time.time() + duration
                self.threadLocal.sch.run()
          elif error == False:
                print 'Connection failed'
                os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)

        def oneround(self):
          if not self.stoprequest.isSet():
            try:
                self.threadLocal.s.send(self.threadLocal.message)
                self.threadLocal.next_time += self.threadLocal.delay
                if self.duration != 0 and time.time() > self.timeout:
                        print '\n' + 'Client socket closed after ' + str(self.duration) + ' seconds'
                        self.threadLocal.s.close()
                        os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
                else:
                        self.threadLocal.sch.enterabs(self.threadLocal.next_time, 0, self.oneround, ())

            except IOError as (errno, strerror):
                if errno == 111:
                        print '\n' + 'Connection lost'
                        self.threadLocal.s.close()
                        os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)

        def join(self, timeout=None):
          self.stoprequest.set()
          super(Client, self).join(timeout)

class calculator(threading.Thread):

        def __init__(self, parent = None):
          super(calculator, self).__init__(parent)

        def run(self):
          self.stoprequest = threading.Event()
          mb = 1048576.00
          while not self.stoprequest.isSet():
                sent = {}
                recv = {}
                inwards = []
                out = []
                total = []
                n = 1
                for i in ni.interfaces():
                        counter = psutil.net_io_counters(pernic=True)[i]
                        sent.update({n:counter.bytes_sent})
                        recv.update({n:counter.bytes_recv})
                        n +=1
                time.sleep(1)
                n = 1
                for i in ni.interfaces():
                        counter = psutil.net_io_counters(pernic=True)[i]
                        totalsent = counter.bytes_sent - sent[n]
                        totalrecv = counter.bytes_recv - recv[n]
                        alldata = totalsent + totalrecv
                        self.totalout = (totalsent/mb) * 8
                        self.totalin = (totalrecv/mb) * 8
                        self.totalinout = (alldata/mb) * 8
                        inwards.insert((n-1), float("%.2f" % self.totalin))
                        out.insert((n-1), float("%.2f" % self.totalout))
                        total.insert((n-1), float("%.2f" % self.totalinout))
                        n += 1
                inwards = sum(inwards)
                out = sum(out)
                total = sum(total)
                if not self.stoprequest.isSet():
                        sys.stdout.write('\r' + 'Out ' + str(out) + 'Mb/s     ' + 'In ' + str(inwards) + 'Mb/s     '   'Total ' + str(total) + 'Mb/s   ')
                        sys.stdout.flush()

        def join(self, timeout=None):
          self.stoprequest.set()
          super(calculator, self).join(timeout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
        f = open('1024','w')
        for i in range(0, 962):
                f.write('@')
        f.close()


        def valid_interfaces():
                for i in ni.interfaces():
                        try:
                                ip = ni.ifaddresses(i)[ni.AF_INET6][0]['addr']
                                if not ip.startswith('fe80') and not i.startswith('lo'):
                                        list.insert(0,i)
                        except KeyError:
                                print 'Interface \"' + i + '\" does not have an IP address'

        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Send Ipv6 traffic through your network')
        group1 = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
        group2 = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
        mode = 0
        list = []
        threads = []
        ports = []
        valid_interfaces()

        group1.add_argument('-g', '--gui',
                        action='store_true', dest='gui',
                        help='Start graphical user interface. Do not use other arguments with this option')
        group1.add_argument('-s', '--server',
                        action='store_true', dest='server',
                        help='Set the program to run in server mode')
        group1.add_argument('-c', '--client',
                        action='store_true', dest='client',
                        help='Set the program to run in client mode')
        group2.add_argument('-i', '--interface',
                        action='store', dest='interface', choices=list,
                        help='Specifies the interface for server')
        group2.add_argument('-d', '--destip',
                        action='store', dest='targetip',
                        help='Sets the destination IPv6 address eg.2001:dead:beef::1')
        parser.add_argument('-p', '--port',
                        action='store', dest='port', type=int,
                        help='Specifies the port used by server or client | Default 5001', default=5001)
        parser.add_argument('-t', '--time',
                        action='store', dest='time', type=int,
                        help='Client only. Specifies in seconds how long traffic will be sent | Default (0) is unlimited', default=0)
        parser.add_argument('-r', '--rate',
                        action='store', dest='rate', type=int,
                        help='Client only. Sets the rate at which traffic will be sent (use plain numbers such as 1 or 1.5) | Default 1Mb/s', default=1)

        if len(sys.argv)==1:
                parser.print_help()
                sys.exit(1)

        args = parser.parse_args()

        if args.gui:
                app = QApplication(sys.argv)
                app.setStyle('cleanlooks')
                mainwindow = Application()
                mainwindow.show()
                sys.exit(app.exec_())

        if args.server and args.interface:
                thread1 = Server(host=args.interface, port=args.port)
                thread1.start()
                mode = 1

        if args.client and args.targetip:
                thread1 = Client(args.targetip, args.port, args.rate, args.time)
                thread1.start()
                mode = 2

        if mode != 0 and thread1.isAlive():
                thread2 = calculator()   
                thread2.start()

        if threading.active_count() > 1:
                while threading.active_count > 1:
                        try:
                                time.sleep(0.01)
                        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                                thread1.join()
                                if mode == 1:
                                        print '\n' + 'Server stopped'
                                elif mode == 2:
                                        print '\n' + 'Client stopped'
                                thread2.join()
                                sys.exit()
        else:
                parser.print_help()
                sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: I can tell you where your error comes from. You should put `self.stoprequest = threading.Event()` into the constructor. Otherwise it will be created only when the thread is launched and you cannot be sure when this will be. This might also solve your exception handling problem.

Comment: Thank you, this did indeed rid me of the exception. The error with thread2.start() still persist, but I believe that's going outside the scope of this question.